# Jqgrid rowid issue

Tags: jqgrid

While updating data from form to grid, same time two `rowid` get updated with the same id.

1. avoided refreshing the grid
2. when I filter the record adding duplicated records in the grid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have 3 control on the view 
1. Text box for EmpID 
2. Date Control for Date
3. Drop-down for Department Selection
  one button for Add/Update  action (add or update data in the grid based on EmpID)
in the grid all ready 5 records are there from data base
 i have added a 6th records in the grid 
 the moment i select  6th row (EmpID 6) record, radio button in the grid to show the data in the respective control for further modification 
it's display the data of 1st row let say EMPID 1

Comment: i investigate the root cause of the behavior and found that while updating the record JQgrid update the 2 rows with same id 
In the grid i have set column sorting on the EMPID. Hope i;m clear to explain my concern.  Thanks

Comment: Now it seems more descriptive but it would look better if you edit your question and add everything there

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i was in medical emergency. I can't post source code here as per my organisation policy. It would be helpful if you mail me your mail id @ pankajk85@gmail.com and i will share description with screen sort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The rowis's in jqGrid should be unique and there should be no duplicated ids. Any duplication of row id's will cause unexpected results like described from you.